# Should I dispose readonly FileStream

Tags: c#, .net

I have a readonly FileStream which is a method local variable:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
   var fileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
   ... //some stream operations
}
```

Should I call Dispose (explicitly or by "using") at the end of the method? What will it change?

Comment: Always dispose. Always dispose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fail to dispose, the `FileStream` won't be closed until the GC kicks in (non-deterministically).

And until this happens, you will be holding an open file handle, preventing some types of access to the file (e.g. writing, deletion).

Note that specifying `FileShare.ReadWrite` won't necessarily help - if another writer attempts to open the file with `FileShare.None` (e.g. by calling `File.OpenWrite`), he won't be able to do so until you close the file.

So, yes, do close the file, with a `using` statement.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter what it does, `IDisposable` is implemented by `FileStream`, and so you need to call `Dispose` implicitly or explicitly when you've finished using it. It is part of the contract of using the class in your code.

Comment: Your usage of the word contract is important.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's best to wrap that in a `using` statement. You also need exception handling if you really want that code to be robust. It will work as it is now, it's just bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

It is a must to dispose any instance implementing `IDisposable` and a good practice to dispose  it trough `using` statement.

Don't think that analyzing every case in particular would help.

Answer (score 0):

If an object can be disposed, you should dispose it as early as you don't need it anymore. From [FileStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) topic:

> If a process terminates with part of a file locked or closes a file
>   that has outstanding locks, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggested: dispose every `IDisposable`, preferably with `using`.

Now for files there could be special case when you really want to block everyone else from accessing/modifying the file. In this case you'd still dispose file at some point, but this "some point" can be significantly later in the code/application lifetime.

Comment: "there could be special case when you really want to block everyone else" - if so, you should hold a static reference to the open FileStream, so that you can deterministically close it when you no longer want it to be blocked.

Comment: @Joe, yes, that is what I was trying to say (also I'd try to not say "static" as most people will read it as `static` when you really mean "variable with lifetime outside single method call")